# Proving $A \times (B \cap C) = (A \times B) \cap (A \times C)$ using induction.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction

first question here.

I need to prove that $A \times (B \cap C) = (A \times B) \cap (A \times C)$, using induction.

The tactic sounds familiar for sequences, though, (Let $\alpha _n$ be a random sequence, if $a_1$ is true, let $a_k$ be true, if we prove it for $a_{k+1}$ we finished) and I do not know how to implement this to set algebra.

The solution is apparent using Venn diagrams but I'll be needing a strong inducted proof.

Comment: Where is that $k$ involved in?!!

Comment: @B.S. Nowhere. It's a random example of inductive proof on a sequence.

Comment: $k$ comes from the definition of mathematical induction. Actually the question is "how to involve $k$ in such a problem.

Comment: @ZaferSernikli No, it is not. The question is in the title. It's just that I have only used inductive proof in sequences, and now I am asked to do this on an a set equation. 

I'm sorry, I'm a bit clueless. Maybe the question has confused.

Comment: And as I understand, you have to make the induction on order of $A$. Assume $A$ has one element, then shot that this is true. Then assume $A$ has $k$ elements and the proposition is satisfied, then show that if $A$ has $k$ elements, the proposition is satisfied.

Comment: @DimitrisS. What I meant with "question" was the "tricky part".

Comment: @ZaferSernikli I rewrote the question better, I believe.

Comment: @ZaferSernikli Alright, thank you for your tip. I'll prove for A having 1 element, assume A with k elements is true then try to prove for A having k+1 elements, correct?

Comment: Yes you're correct. I didn't post it as an answer as it's not a full answer, but it should be easy to prove it, I suppose.

Comment: The trouble with using induction to prove things about sets is that the proof is only valid for _finite_ sets. Here the set-theoretic proof, as well as being more natural, actually proves the proposition for any sets.

Comment: @TonyK You're wrong. Induction does not only prove things for finite sets, but also countably infinite sets.

Comment: @Zafer: You're wrong. If you were right, you could use induction to prove that all countable sets are finite.

Comment: @ZaferSernikli: yes, induction on $\mathbb N$ *does* only work for finite set, as the conclusion would be $\forall n\in \mathbb N, \forall A, B, C, card(A) = n \Rightarrow ...$. However, the OP could perform induction on cardinals, and assuming the axiom of choice, every set has a cardinal, hence it would prove the statement for all sets. I doubt however that this is what was asked, the OP should provide details about where this comes from.

Comment: If induction for those types of proofs worked for only finite sets, then you could find a $M$ such that if $\text{card}(A)>M$, then there cannot be a proof based on induction on sets. However, induction itself is inducable, that is if $\forall k, P(k)$ can be proved with induction in such a way: $P(1) \land (P(k) \implies P(k+1)$, then $\forall k, P(k+1)$ can be proved in the same way, then you cannot find such an $M$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Induction is an unnatural way of proving this identity.

Obvious proofs are:

- Use the definitions of $A \times (B \cap C)$ and $(A \times B) \cap (A \times C)$; we manipulate one to give the other.
  \begin{align*}
  A \times (B \cap C) &= \{(a,d):a \in A \text{ and } d \in B \cap C\} \\
    &= \{(a,d):a \in A \text{ and } d \in B \text{ and } d \in C\} \\
    &= \{(a,d):a \in A \text{ and } d \in B \text{ and } a \in A \text{ and } d \in C\} \\
    &= \{(a,d):(a,d) \in A \times B \text{ and } (a,d) \in A \times C\} \\
    &= (A \times B) \cap (A \times C)
  \end{align*}
- Or prove that $(a,d) \in A \times (B \cap C)$ if and only if $(a,d) \in (A \times B) \cap (A \times C)$ [which is essentially the same as the above].

These are low-level and simple proofs that work for arbitrary sets.

Proving this using induction has limitations:

- It will only work for finite sets $A$, $B$ and $C$.  Yes, induction can be used to prove things about countably infinite sets, but in this case, the infinite set will be the set of cardinalities of $A$, $B$, and $C$ [not the sets $A$, $B$ and $C$ themselves], so we will only be able to prove that the claim is true for all $(|A|,|B|,|C|) \in \mathbb{Z}^{\geq 0} \times \mathbb{Z}^{\geq 0} \times \mathbb{Z}^{\geq 0}$ (where $|A|$, $|B|$, and $|C|$ are all finite).
- This problem is "three dimensional": we can vary the problem by increasing $|A|$, $|B|$, or $|C|$.

---

Here's a proof by induction.  We let $P(i,j,k)$ be the property "$A \times (B \cap C)=(A \times B) \cap (A \times C)$ for all sets $A,B,C$ with $|A|=i$, $|B|=j$, and $|C|=k$".  The induction works by showing:

- $P(0,j,k)$ is true,
- $P(1,j,k)$ is true, and
- $P(0,j,k),\ldots,P(i-1,j,k)$ imply $P(i,j,k)$ when $i \geq 2$.

*Base case 1*: We prove the claim when $A=\emptyset$.  We have
\begin{align*}
A \times (B \cap C) &= \emptyset \times (B \cap C) \\
 &= \emptyset \\
 &= \emptyset \cap \emptyset \\
 &= (\emptyset \times B) \cap (\emptyset \times C) \\
 &= (A \times B) \cap (A \times C).
\end{align*}

*Base case 2*: We prove the claim when $A=\{a\}$.  We have
\begin{align*}
\{a\} \times (B \cap C) &= \{(a,d):d \in B \cap C\} \\
 &= \{(a,d):d \in B \text{ and } d \in C\} \\
 &= \{(a,d):a \in A \text{ and } d \in B \text{ and } a \in A \text{ and } d \in C\} \\
 &= (A \times B) \cap (A \times C).
\end{align*}

*Inductive step*: We induct on the size of $A$; and assume $|A| \geq 2$.  Assume $X \times (B \cap C)=(X \times B) \cap (X \times C)$ whenever $|X|<|A|$.  Then, for any $a \in A$, we have $|A \setminus \{a\}|<|A|$ and $|\{a\}|=1<|A|$, so
\begin{align*}
A \times (B \cap C) &= ((A \setminus \{a\}) \times (B \cap C)) \cup (\{a\} \times (B \cap C)) \\
 &= (((A \setminus \{a\}) \times B) \cap ((A \setminus \{a\}) \times C)) \cup ((\{a\} \times B) \cap (\{a\} \times C)) \\
 &= \quad \vdots \\
 &= (A \times B) \cap (A \times C)
\end{align*}
omitting the tedious manipulations.

It works, but it's slower than (and virtually contains) the obvious method.

Comment: I realised earlier that it was a mistake to go about this using induction. In any case, thank you for your (very) complete answer.