# Proving $A\times (B\cap C)=(A \times B)\cap (A\times C)$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Given sets $A$, $B$, and $C$, prove $A\times (B\cap C)=(A \times B)\cap (A\times C)$.

It is an assignment and we have to submit it tomorrow. We are really get stuck on this and need some help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi ali!  Given this is homework, most likeley no one will do the problem for you.  But we can certainly help you through it.  You need to know a couple of things.  To prove set equality, you have to show that $A\times(B \cap C) \subset (A \times B) \cap (A \times C)$ and $(A \times B) \cap (A \times C) \subset A\times(B \cap C)$.

Comment: Hi christopher! thank you for your guidance...I appreciate it)

Comment: No problem.  The next thing you need to do is start trying to prove the first condition.  So, let $x \in A \times (B \cap C)$.  What does that mean?  By the definition of the Cartesian product and set intersection, $x \in \{(m,n)|m \in A, n \in (B \cap C)\}$.  Now try and get to where $x \in \{(m,n)|m \in (A \times B), n \in (A \times C)\}$.

Comment: cool, now it looks easy than before...really))

Comment: Glad we could help.

Comment: I'm sorry I changed the $\cap$ to $\cup$ by mistake - I was distracted.

Comment: hey..but it's not all... i have like 7 more questions that i have been stuck on :)

Comment: Shaun, at least you realized it and changed back=)..so no reason to worry)

Comment: See the first part of [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/594052/11994) for a proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let 
$(x,y) \in A \times (B\cap C) $
Then $x \in A$ and $y \in B \cap C$ which implies that $y \in B$ and $y \in C$.

Hence by the definition of cartesain product $(x,y) \in A \times B$.

If you follow in this manner you'll get $(x,y) \in A \times B \cap A \times C$ so $A \times (B\cap C) \subseteq A \times B \cap A \times C$. Similarly for the other direction.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Proceed by a sequence of equivalences, starting with

- $(x,y) \in A \times (B \cap C)$

and ending with

- $(x,y) \in (A \times B) \cap (A \times C).$